# how can you tell if github repository is for python 2 or python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, github

I'm interested in running [this code from github](https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style) – how do I know if it was written for python2 or python3?

I'm hoping this is a really basic question and there is just some part of the site which makes this obvious.

Comment: You can check if there are `print <expr>` statements versus `print(<expr>)` statements. Although not all repos have such print statements. It will already do some checking.

Comment: Furthermore in Python-2.x `02` is allowed with (or any non-zero digit) after a zero digit. In Python-3.x that is not allowed. So there are some syntactical hints.

Comment: I tried searching for things like "print" and "items", but there is none. The code may very well be fully-compatible with both, if not impacted by any of the changes that make version 3. Usually is it the job of the maintainer to provide this info in setup.py.

Comment: About print statements; even if you have seen some `print(<expr>)` it does not mean it is Python3. Python2 also allows that.

Answer (score 3):

You could download the source and run the 2to3 script to see if it proposes changes to upgrade it to python3:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

If there are no changes, then it is Python3 (and maybe also Python2) code.